# How to update observable after Enter key pressed in the Internet Explorer

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding, typescript

HTML code

```html
<input type="text" data-bind="value: nextName">
```

Observable

```js
nextName: KnockoutComputed<string>;
currentName: KnockoutObservable<string>;

constructor()
{
    this.nextName = ko.pureComputed(
    {
        read: () => this.currentName(),
        write: (value: string) =>
        {
           this.currentName(value);
           if ((value) && value.trim().length > 0)
              this.runSearch();
        }
    }, this);
}
```

After user press enter - searching will be executed normally in Chrome for example, but not in Internet Explorer.
I tried to use binding with `valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'`, but this will execute searching after every character - which not what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `textInput` binding and create a `custom Knockout binding` for `enterkey` to do what you want : 
`textInput` provides two-way updates between the `viewmodel` property and the element’s value .it provides instance updates for `autocomplete`, `drag-and-drop`, and `clipboard` events. Then you can use `enterkey` binding to call your function every time user presses the enter key and that should work in IE as well.

```
 <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: nextName,enterkey: function() {runSearch()}">
```

**custom Knockout binding:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.enterkey = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel) {
        var callback = valueAccessor();
        $(element).keypress(function (event) {
            var keyCode = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
            if (keyCode === 13) {
                callback.call(viewModel);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
};
```

Working example :http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5124/

Answer (score 2):

I used this polyfill - the root issue is that IE doesn't fire the `change` event when the `Enter` key is pressed.

```
var isIE = !!document.documentMode;
if (isIE) {

    $("body").on("keydown", "input[type='text']", function (e) {

        // Ensure 'value' binding is fired on enter in IE
        if ((e.keyCode || e.which) === 13) {
            $(this).blur();
        }
    });
}
```